# why does this string not contain the correct characters?

Tags: string, delphi, serial-port, delphi-xe3

Written in Delphi XE3, my software is communicating with an instrument that occasionally sends binary data.  had expected I should use AnsiString since this data will never be Unicode.  I couldn't believe that the following code doesn't work as I had expected.  I'm supposing that the characters I'm exposing it to are considered illegitimate...

```
var
  s:AnsiString;
begin
  s:='test' + chr(128);

  // had expected that since the string was set above to end in #128, 
  // it should end in #128...it does not.
  if ord(s[5])<>128 then
    ShowMessage('String ending is not as expected!');
end;
```

Naturally, I could use a pointer to accomplish this but I would think I should probably be using a different kind of string.  of course, I could use a byte array but a string would be more convenient.

really, I'd like to know "why" and have some good alternatives.

thanks!

Comment: Please could you edit your question to explain what you mean by "doesn't work as I had expected"? What is the actual and expected output, or exact error message?

Comment: improved my question

Comment: Which version of Delphi are using? In Delphi 2009+, `AnsiString` is codepage-aware, characters 128-255 are codepage-specific, and `Chr()` is Unicode-sensitive.  If you don't care about Unicode and want 128 to be treated as-is as then use `AnsiChar(128)` instead of `Chr(128)`.

Comment: AnsiChar(128) or #128 works.

Comment: thank you; AnsiChar( ) took care of this.  #___ would've addressed it but i needed the value determined at runtime.  Remy, i'd like to accept yours as an answer.  thanks!

Comment: @LURD: `#128` is subject to [`{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)), whereas `AnsiChar(128)` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you observe stems from the fact that `Chr(128)` is a UTF-16 `WideChar` representing [U+0080](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm).

When translated to your ANSI locale this does not map to ordinal 128. I would expect U+0080 to have no equivalent in your ANSI locale and therefore map to `?` to indicate a failed translation.

Indeed the compiler will even warn you that this can happen. You code when compiled with default compiler options yields these warnings:

```
W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'
W1062 Narrowing given wide string constant lost information
```

Personally I would use configure the warnings to treat both of those warnings as errors.

The fundamental issue is revealed here:

> My software is communicating with an instrument that occasionally sends binary data.

The correct data type for byte oriented binary data is an array of byte. In Delphi that would be `TBytes`.

It is wrong to use `AnsiString` since that exposes you to codepage translations. You want to be able to specify ordinal values and you categorically do not want text encodings to play a part. You do not want for your program's behaviour to be determined by the prevailing ANSI locale.

Strings are for text. For binary use byte arrays.